# how to display information on mouse over in the form of gridview or table

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView. Everytime there is a mouse over on an Id in the gridview I want to display additional information with multiple rows in the form of a table or gridvew. I'am currently working on asp.net C#. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try the jQuery UI Dialog.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  Or what your personal research has pulled up?  There are lots of non-modal dialog (popup) solutions out there.

Comment: i followed everything that was implemented in the following link http://www.iamraghuveer.com/2012/04/display-gridview-row-details-using.html